# How to use android seekbar to display time selection?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have tried seekbar normal task to display the time from 1 to 12 but I have little different requirement.
[image]

please some body can help me to get seekbar show value exactly like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your seek bar have a range from min to max. You must define what range you need. For example you want to choose date with seek bar from 0:00 to 23:59 with step of 15 minutes. So you need range bar with min = 0 and max = 24 * 4.
When your seek bar is changed you need to calculate actual selected time. For that, you can get SeekBar progress and multiply it to 15 minutes. And you will get selected minutes.

Example code:

```
seekBar.setMax(24 * 4); //24 hours and 4 step in one hour.

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangetListener() {
  public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
     int hours = progress / 4; // it will return hours.
     int minutes = (progress % 4) * 15; // here will be minutes.
  }
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: A little help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869158/how-to-set-time-range-using-seekbar)

Comment: @Alexander, Hi. I need your .  Can you explain me all that terms which you had use for this ?

Comment: @nihal_softy what do you mean by "all that terms"? It's just very basic math

Comment: @AlexanderMikhaylov HI Thank you so much for reply. Actually What I did this here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261792/set-time-in-hhmm-format-in-seek-range-bar/46262041?noredirect=1#comment79487505_46262041

I follwed your step but still it's not showing exact time what I want. I want set time from morning 7:30 am to night 10:30 PM

Comment: @nihal_softy I answered question on the link