# How to formats the min and max value of android-range-seek-bar ?

Tags: android

I use the control android-range-seek-bar at https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar to show two thumb controls allowing a range to be selected.

I hope to the Text indicating the selected min and max values on the bar are formatted as "hh:mm:ss", I have created a function `ConvertSecondsToHMmSs`, how can I do that? Such as 1000L disply "00:00:01"

And more, I hope to do something when min or max value changed,  but there is only the event `public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Long minValue, Long maxValue)`, it can't differentiate which value, min or max value, is changed. I hope to do **A** when min value changed, and do **B** when max value changed!

**Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RangeSeekBar<Long> seekBar = (RangeSeekBar<Long>) findViewById(R.id.myRangeSeekBar);
        seekBar.setRangeValues(1000L,2000L);
}


private String ConvertSecondsToHMmSs(long millis) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
}
```

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:rsb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/myRangeSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        rsb:absoluteMaxValue="150"
        rsb:absoluteMinValue="20"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cuiwei.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23243644/1061944 Hope this link helps you out

Comment: Thanks! but  stackoverflow.com/a/23243644/1061944  can't do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fairly simple, though you'll need to modify the original `RangeSeekBar`:

[image]

1.

- Copy `RangeSeekBar` class into your project
- Add your `convertSecondsToHMmSs` into your custom `RangeSeekBar` class
- In `onDraw` method of `RangeSeekBar`:

  replace (lines 646-647)

  ```
      String minText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMinValue());
      String maxText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMaxValue());
  ```

  with

  ```
      String minText;
      String maxText;
      if (getSelectedMinValue() instanceof Long && getSelectedMaxValue() instanceof Long) {
          minText = String.valueOf(convertSecondsToHMmSs((Long)getSelectedMinValue()));
          maxText = String.valueOf(convertSecondsToHMmSs((Long)getSelectedMaxValue()));
      } else {
          minText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMinValue());
          maxText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMaxValue());
      }
  ```

  (of course, this can be generalized for broader use!)

2.
To distinguish min/max border change - just store the previous values and compare them:

```
    Long currentMin = 1000L, currentMax = 2000L;

    ......

    RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar = (RangeSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.myRangeSeekBar);
    rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(currentMin, currentMax);
    rangeSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar bar, Object minValue, Object maxValue) {
            if (!currentMin.equals(minValue)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Min border changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (!currentMax.equals(maxValue)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Max border changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            currentMin = (Long)minValue;
            currentMax = (Long)maxValue;
        }
    });
```

Comment: A little help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869158/how-to-set-time-range-using-seekbar)?