# Range seek bar with fixed gap between two thumbs

Tags: android, android-seekbar

[image]

I have a Custom `RangeSeekBar` with `dual thumb`. The thumbs seem to be intersect each other when i drag both of them.

How i can put a fixed gap such that the thumbs don't meet each other and maintain say a minimum gap of some value e.g.10. Below is the image. The two thumbs (right and left) should not meet with each other. There should be some gap

Comment: check this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260789/how-to-formats-the-min-and-max-value-of-android-range-seek-bar

Comment: yes, i am using the same custom range seekbar, but unable to find process to restrict the two thumbs to collide @Adilhusen

Answer (score 0):

Set a Min Value and Max Value for the RangeBar on initialization. After that just store the previous values and compare them.

```
Long mMin = 50L,mMax = 1000L;

    RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar = (RangeSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.myRangeSeekBar);
    rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(mMin, mMax);
    rangeSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar bar, Object minValue, Object maxValue) {
            if (!mMin.equals(minValue)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Min Value changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (!mMax.equals(maxValue)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Max Value changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And how does it stop the two thumbs to be on top of each other? @shivaSnape

Comment: I didnt Get you , what you mean by stop ? Coud you please tell whay you actually mean? @arun

Comment: Edited my answer with picture @shiva snape