# How to set time range using seekbar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I stumbled upon [this library by Anothem](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar). Basically it provides a `SeekBar` similar to the default Android one, but with two thumb controls allowing a range to be selected, and some other extras as well.

As at the moment the `seekbar` can select range between `numbers/digits` but cannot be used for actual `time` range selection in `12 hours` system like `12am-3pm`.

I am tring to achieve the above but with no success.

After looking through stackoverflow i stumbled again at a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243275/how-to-use-android-seekbar-to-display-time-selection?lq=1) but cannot seem to reuse or implement for my case.

Similarly a [github repo](https://github.com/maheshwarLigade/RangeSeekBar) promised to solve the issue but after running the class, i simply cannot see the changes.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

[Here is the class to modify.](http://pastebin.com/QVD84EPv)

How i used it:

```js
RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar = (RangeSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(15, 90);
        rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(20);
        rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(88);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you setting the range values from 15 to 90? If you are trying to depict time, you should set the range values as:

```
rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(0,24 * SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
```

where `SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION` is the smallest block of time you can select (`2` to select every half hour, `4` for every quarter hour (15 minutes), `60` for every minute).

Then, to determine the time the user selected, use:

```
int minHour = rangeSeekBar.getSelectedMinValue() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
int minMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rangeSeekBar.getSelectedMinValue() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
int maxHour = rangeSeekBar.getSelectedMaxValue() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
int maxMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rangeSeekBar.getSelectedMaxValue() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The first part i agree, but the part where i determine the time user selected, i kept being told "operator / cannot be applied to T", see line 586 on pastebin above.

Comment: @SteveKamau I assume you are trying to use type T to represent a time value. Why not explicitly use a float or double and determine the time based on that value? You can then add methods that use the calculations above, such as getSelectedMinTime() and getSelectedMaxTime()

Comment: Aaahh amazing!! Now i get it, thatnks alot!!

Comment: its not working for me sometimes it gives time like 2:70 am or 2:90 am

Comment: @SteveKamau Can you post sample if you got it to work?
Also how would i got about making this a circular seekbar?

Comment: @Codes12 check this out https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5314 . It is a Circle SeekBar inspired by Android Holo ColorPicker. See how you can use it. Here's the entire list https://android-arsenal.com/tag/83?sort=created. Hope this helps.

Comment: HI everyone. Do you have any working example on it ? I am trying but getting not satisfactory answer. Please let me know how can I get accurate value in HH:MM format?

Comment: @NihalSrivastava any luck...?